# Meteor and Session/Common Data

Tags: javascript, meteor

Progressing along with my isomorphic javascript crusade, I put Meteor on a hold while I played a bit more with the MEAN stack. To ward off any further procastination, I've decided to finish my original prototype community application. Now, my biggest issue with Meteor isn't reactivity, it's session/common data.

I know Meteor's native session system is based off of the reactive concept, and cookies don't "exist" because Meteor operates on "the wire". Though let's say I were building an application on the LAMP or mean STACK, and I was creating a user interface. I'd use cookies/sessions to control user activity. If Meteor operates off of reactivity, how do I maintain persistence?

I have searched through atmosphere for packages that fit my criteria, and I ran into a couple of packages that store "presistent sessions". Though these interfaces operate off of the client, not the server; hence my code would be exposed client, therefor setting the application up for exploitaton.

All that being stated, I know Meteor has it's standard user interface. What I'm trying to do here is understand Meteor, and gain experience for future endevours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meteor has a built-in login system that keeps track of the logged-in user, which is one of the main reasons people use cookies. If you want to store other data on the client in a persistent way, you can use the HTML5 `localStorage` API.

I think what you're referring to is that something like PHP lets you store data in a "SESSION" variable that is actually stored on the server, but persisted between different requests from the same client.

If this is what you are looking for, there are several approaches that will give you similar functionality:

1. Store data associated with a particular user, and use the `userId` that Meteor gives you to only publish it for that user (using [Meteor.publish](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/publish_userId))
2. Have a randomly generated client ID that is stored in `localStorage`, and pass that in when calling subscriptions or methods to authenticate as that client. This will work in the case where the user is not logged in, and will give you a very similar result to cookies/session in PHP. You will still store the actual data in the database on the server, but you will know which data is associated with a particular client by the unique ID.

It's true that Meteor's `Session` variable is named in a way that can be confusing if you are coming from PHP where `SESSION` means something totally different.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: You sir, are my hero. Thanks a bunch!